# How to check convergence of the following series 7

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Is this series convergent?
>   $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{\frac{1}{n}})\quad\text{where $0<q<1$}.$$ 
>   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for $n\geq 1$, the function $f(q)=q^{1/n}$ is concave, [its graph stays under the tangent line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable) at $1$, that is, for $q\geq 0$, 
$$q^{1/n}=f(q)\leq f(1)+f'(1)(q-1)=1+\frac{q-1}{n},$$
which implies that for $q\in (0,1)$
$$1-q^{1/n}\geq \frac{1-q}{n}>0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=1-q^{1/n}$. Hence $q=(1-a_n)^n$. The Bernoulli inequality gives:

$q \ge 1-na_n$, hence $a_n \ge \frac{1-q}{n}$.